# Socket connection over WiFi in android

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi

I m trying to implement a socket connection over a wifi to read some data. can any one please help me how i can achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Like in java you just need the internet permission.

Comment: so i get the server ip address and connect it is it

Comment: Right. Like in any other language.

Answer (score -1):

See the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html). You also need to add the [internet permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) to your manifest.